# Django: access to attributes of custom model field from html template

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I implemented a custom model field:

```
class CustomCharField(models.CharField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.my_attr = "MY_ATTR"
```

Now I want to be able to display that additional attribute when I'm iterating over all model's fields in `change_form_template`:

```
{% block field_sets %}
    {% for fieldset in adminform %}
        {% for line in fieldset %}
            {% for field in line %}
                {{ field.field }}

                {% if field.field.my_attr %}
                    {{ field.field.my_attr }}
                {% endif %}

            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Unfortunately `my_attr` is not visible. I was searching the proper method in the django docs but without any success. I was also trying to use the custom `form_class` (inheriting from `django.forms.fields.CharField`)

EDIT:

Ok, so I need both custom form field and model field. Given the following code, what should I change to make it working? (of course I ignore passing the attribute value in that example). Why `my_attr` from `CustomFormField` is still not accessible from the template?

```
class CustomFormField(fields.CharField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.my_attr = "MY_ATTR2"

class CustomCharField(models.CharField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.my_attr = "MY_ATTR"

    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        defaults = {'form_class': CustomFormField}
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return super().formfield(**defaults)
```

Comment: If you want to customize a field in the template, you need to create your own `forms.CharField`, not `models.CharField`. Otherwise, it would be like trying to show another model field attribute in the template and that's not possible (e.g. you can not print `field.default` or `field.required` inside a template).

Comment: You make a custom model field here `CustomCharField(models.CharField)` not a form field. `field.field` gives you the form field for the bound field not the model field.

Comment: @Guillaume thanks, I edited the question.

Comment: Thanks, @AbdulAzizBarkat

Answer (score 1):

Ok, thanks to the advices from @AbdulAzizBarkat and @Guillaume I finally managed how to resolve the problem.

In order to expose attribute of the model field at the HTML template, it's needed to implement also custom form field and pass the attribute in `default` dict in `formfield` method:

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import fields

class CustomFormField(fields.CharField):
    def __init__(self, my_attr, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.my_attr = my_attr


class CustomCharField(models.CharField):
    def __init__(self, my_attr, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.my_attr = my_attr

    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        defaults = {'form_class': CustomFormField, "my_attr": self.my_attr}
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return super().formfield(**defaults)
```

Another change is the way of accessing to the attribute in the HTML template specified by setting `change_form_template` value. In that case it should be `{{ field.field.field.my_attr }}`